# Apache on Ubuntu and default website w/ VirtualHost

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

i've read that apache on ubuntu requires the first virtualhost file included will be the default website, so everyone prefixes the virtual host file with '000-'

is there anyway around this, such as using *default* or another option? i would like the default site to be a different file which i cannot change the name of the file so cannot prefix it with 000 (its a hard coded system, and the configs are generated automatically)